# My Ubuntu Gnome Terminal dosen't work properly

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, gnome-terminal, error-handling

When I try to update it shows this error. I use Ubuntu 20.04

`404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/pulp/ubuntu focal Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in 
from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in 
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/pulp/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code`

Before this happens to me, I upgraded my python3 version to 3.9.6. This is affect to some gnome app like gnome tweek(dosen't open). Currently I'm using kernel 5.10.

###### When I type wrong command it shows crash message

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in 
from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in 
from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in 
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`

##### Please help me to fix this.

Comment: PPA's are 3rd party sources, so all checks on are they trustworthy, maintained properly etc are on you - did you perform those checks? as they should have shown no support is available for *focal* or 20.04 (and a few years since support was provided should also have been a concern...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade OS to repair broken package by type:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

or you can update packages URL. [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-fix-ubuntu-debian-apt-get-404-not-found-repository-errors) article will help you